# strange codes in text, like +ADs-, +AGA-, or +ACoAKg- and +ACEAIQ-

Tags: encoding, email, ascii

i got a dataset that uses a strange encoding for non-printables / diacritics. i'm getting hte impression that it's an artifact of some mail system. or maybe it's excel or something? anyway, the stuff i get looks like this:

+ADs-, +AGA-, or +ACoAKg- and +ACEAIQ-

there's more.... any idea what that this and where it comes from? google shows me stuff from mailing lists etc - but theys just look like mangeled mail, nothing discussing the codes themselve.

Interestingly, Excel seems to know what to do with them. Might be something like quoted printable... just different :) any idea?

Comment: examples of such codes in mail archives:

http://www.mail-archive.com/usma@colostate.edu/msg08732.html

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tapestry-users/200401.mbox/%3CA27FEC8516051048B5B3A119BC0D8CB60181BEE9@exch2k.spheranet.com%3E

Comment: to answer my own question: it's UTF-7. duh. thanks bryan.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like UTF-7 encoding. See [wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) for the gory detail, also [RFC2152](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2152) for more gory details (including a few more examples).